# WPF MVVM vs Постраничная навигация

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Дано: Проект при написании которого стараюсь придерживаться MVVM.
В проекте постраничная навигация. Всё было неплохо пока на одной из страниц перед навигацией не понадобилось проводить валидацию введённых данных и осуществлять переход только при успешной валидации...

Осуществляя навигацию непосредственно в VM я нарушаю принцип MVVM 
Если реализовать верификацию с последующей навигацией во View это тоже нарушение MVVM

Событие нажатия кнопки навигации отрабатывает раньше чем команда верификации данных.

Вопрос: Как на C# WPF реализовать навигацию с предварительной верификацией без нарушения принципов MVVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться событиями. Они позволяют общаться вью и VM, не нарушая правил MVVM. Алгоритм следующий:

1. По нажатию на кнопку вью отправляет событие о необходимости
   валидации данных.
2. Обработчик этого события в VM производит валидацию и либо устанавливает
   флажок в переданном аргументе события (например, `IsValidationSuccessful`), либо отправляет новое событие, в котором сообщает о результате валидации.
3. Опираясь на ответ VM, вью либо осуществляет переход страницы, либо
   сообщает пользователю об ошибка (подсветка, сообщение об ошибке и
   т.д.)

Подробнее о событиях на примере MVVM Light Toolkit можно почитать в журнале MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/dn745866.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать валидацию на источнике данных. Ваша ViewModel должна будет реализовать [IDataErrorInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)). Примерно так:

```
class ViewModel : IDataErrorInfo
{
    ...

    protected Dictionary<string, string> ValidationErrors { get; private set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        ValidationErrors = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
    {
        get { return Validate(propertyName); }
    }

    private string Validate(string propertyName)
    {
        var value = GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(this, null);
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        var context = new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = propertyName };

        if (!Validator.TryValidateProperty(value, context, results))
        {
            var errorMessage = results.First().ErrorMessage;
            ValidationErrors[propertyName] = errorMessage;
            return errorMessage;
        }

        ValidationErrors.Remove(propertyName);
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Результаты валидации я сохранил в словарике `ValidationErrors`. Их, например, можно вывести на экран. Кроме того, по ним можно определить наличие ошибок во ViewModel.

Теперь можно определить модель представления страницы:

```
class Page : ViewModel
{
    [Required]
    // не забыть про PropertyChanged
    public string FullName {get; set;}

    public ICommand NextPage {get; private set; }

    public Page()
    {
        NextPage = new Command(
            /* execute */..., 
            /* can execute */ () => !ValidationErrors.Any());
    }
}
```

И представление страницы:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>...</Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Row=0 Text={Binding FullName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidateOnDataErrors=True}/>
    <Button Grid.Row=1 Command={Binding NextPage}/>
</Grid>
```